# Transferring file to virtual machine QEMU using TCP Port 2222 not working

Tags: linux, tcp, kernel, virtual-machine, qemu

So I run the following command to open QEMU :

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 64M -hda ../debian_squeeze_amd64_standard.qcow2 -append "root=/dev/sda1 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8" -kernel arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -nographic -net nic,vlan=1 -net user,vlan=1 -redir tcp:2222::22
```

And the code works and QEMU starts but when I type the following code to code the file newcheck, it shows error :

```
root@debian-amd64:~# scp -P 2222 newcheck root@localhost:~
ssh: connect to host localhost port 2222: Connection refused
lost connection
```

Can someone please let me know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded by changing `-net nic,vlan=1 -net user,vlan=1 -redir tcp:2222::22` to `-net nic,model=e1000 -net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22`.
Hope this helps XD

Recommendation：[#07 - How To Emulate Firmware With QEMU - Hardware Hacking Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yP3QOT-h98)

Comment: Thanks. Right now, I have no idea why I had this question or what I was trying at the time :p

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of qemu "-net" became deprecated and it's advised to use "-netdev" instead. So, try this one:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 64M -hda ../debian_squeeze_amd64_standard.qcow2 -append "root=/dev/sda1 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8" -kernel arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -nographic -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 -device e1000,netdev=net0
```

Comment: You're right, -net has become deprecated, but even with your command, it still shows the same error in copying part after logging into root. Please help.